# How to use Reflection to read Static Properties from a Nested Class?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have some configuration stored in the following data structure which uses nested classes for Organization.

```
public abstract class LogoSpec
{
    public abstract byte[] Logo { get; set; }

    public class Web
    {
        public static float Height { get; set; }

        public class A4 : Web
        {
            public static float Left { get; set; }
        }
    }
}

public class SampleLogo : LogoSpec
{
    public override byte[] Logo { get; set; }
}
```

I can easily use it when I exactly know what value to use at design time

```
// Setting values
SampleLogo.Web.A4.Height = 10.25f;
```

How can I write a function that retrieves this value at runtime?

```
float GetValue(string logoName = "SampleLogo", string layout = "Web", string paperSize = "A4", string property = "Height");
```

Comment: Have you already attempted to get those values through reflection? If so what specific problem did you encounter? If not, go do that.

Comment: Giving you the benefit of the doubt, I will assume that you have already searched the web and Stack Overflow for answers to your scenario, have already made an attempt to implement code to achieve your goal, but for some reason were unable to get it to work. Even making all of those generous assumptions, I still find that the question above needs work, as it lacks a good [mcve] showing all of this, as well as any sort of description of what _specific_ difficulty you are troubled with.

Comment: Tried GetNestedTypes() but it does not return nested types if they come from a base type. Don't know what else I could use from Reflection.

Comment: I think what @PeterDuniho means (and I realized only after answering) that it's not even clear if your problem is to access `Height` or if you even want to find `A4` or `Web` in the first place.

Comment: Let me edit the question to be more clear on what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to get that property is actually very straight forward, but you have to provide all necessary `BindingFlags`:

```
PropertyInfo p = typeof(SampleLogo.Web.A4).GetProperty("Height", 
    BindingFlags.Static | 
    BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | 
    BindingFlags.Public);
```

`FlattenHierarchy` is needed to also get properties of base classes.

Now you can use this `PropertyInfo` to get and set the value:

```
p.SetValue(null, 14f);
float height = (float)p.GetValue(null);
```

---

Update: The complete method could look like this:

```
public float GetValue(string logoName = "LogoSpec", string layout = "Web", string paperSize = "A4", string property = "Height")
{
    Type logoType = Type.GetType(logoName);
    Type layoutType = logoType?.GetNestedType(layout);
    Type paperType = layoutType?.GetNestedType(paperSize);
    PropertyInfo pi = paperType?.GetProperty("Height", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Public);
    return (float?)pi?.GetValue(null) ?? 0f;
}
```

But note that instead for `"LogoSpec"` you would need to use an [AssemblyQualifiedName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname(v=vs.110).aspx) or at least qualify the type name with its namespace.

Comment: Thanks. It was FlattenHierarchy what I was not using.

Comment: @Raj Ok, added the method anyway, I was curious myself how this will work.